# Warning: Cannot modify header information . misc.php

Tags: wordpress

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tomproje/site/sgaotw.com/wp-config.php:1) in /home/tomproje/site/sgaotw.com/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1115

what is the problem online 1115 ? I try to solve this problem , i read every topic about this problem , but not found an answer .

[line 1115](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS1Su.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there could be some blank space in a PHP file somewhere. Try checking your wp-config.php file and seeing if there's a character before the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: i checked , in wp-config.php it's only one  '' <?php " . It's first code .     from wp-config.php -->   <?php
error_reporting(0);
// BEGIN A2 CONFIG
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
// END A2 CONFIG
/** Enable W3 Total Cache */
define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache